# CodeIgniter: return & display multiple rows from DB

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Maybe due to lack of sleep I have some problems with my logic.
In CodeIgniter, I need to get the last 10 posts from the DB and display them on the page.

My Controller is as follows:

```
public function index() {

  // $data is an array containing some useless stuff like title, etc.
  // Never mind.

  // Skipped header & navbar view loaders;
  $this->load->view('blog_page', $data);

  $this->get_latest_posts(1);
}
```

Now the model goes:

```
public function get_latest_posts($i) {
  // $i is a number of posts to be displayed. Now it is 10
  $query = $this->db->get('posts', $i);
  return $query->result();
  // Any clue what to do here, cause I need an array that contains arrays of post rows;
}
```

I've been trying to do a foreach cycle, but it only works when using one row;
I would appreciate your help, guys!

Every answer will have a positive impact on the life of every kitten on a planet.

P.S. I removed any unnecessary stuff from my code, like loading header&footer views.

Answer (score 0):

controller function

```
public function index() {

  // $data is an array containing some useless stuff like title, etc.
  // Never mind.

  // Skipped header & navbar view loaders;
  $this->load->view('blog_page', $data);
  $data['get_latest_post'] = $this->your model name->get_latest_posts(1);
  $this->load->view('your view file name',$data);


}
```

model function

```
public function get_latest_posts($i) {

  $query = $this->db->get('posts', $i);
  $this->db->limit(10);

}
```

is this fine..

Comment: This does not give me a way how to display those 10 rows on the page. It only performs a `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...`. Maybe I wrote my question incorrectly, but all I need to do is to create an array for each row. Like:
`$arr[0]['postname'] = 'trololo'; $arr[1]['postname'] = 'ololo'`, etc.

Comment: you want latest 10 posts from table if i am not wrong?

Comment: I want to display them on the page. I know how to get them from the DB. The problem is to parse an array of those 10 posts and display in a view.

Comment: just updated code plz have a look and let me know if you want anything